# Way to efficiently calculate XOR(^) checksum based on a list of IDs

Tags: python, checksum, xor

When googling information about Python list comprehension I was offered a google foobar challenge, which I've been slowly working on the past few days for fun. The latest challenge:

[image]

effectively calls for generating a list of IDs, ignoring an increasing number from each new line until there's one ID left. Then you are supposed to XOR(^) the IDs to produce a checksum. I created a working program that outputs the correct answer, however it's not efficient enough to pass all test cases(passes 6/10) in the time allotted. A length of 50,000 should produce a result in under 20 seconds, but it takes 320.

Could someone steer me in the right direction, but **please don't do it for me**, I'm having fun pushing myself with this challenge. Perhaps there's a data structure or algorithm I can implement to speed up the computation time?

Logic behind code:

1. First, the starting ID and length are taken in
2. A list of IDs is generated, ignoring an increasing number of IDs from each new line, starting with ignoring 0 from the first line.
3. XORs all of the numbers in the list of IDS using a for loop
4. Answer is returned as an int

---

```
import timeit
def answer(start,length):
    x = start
    lengthmodified = length
    answerlist = []
    for i in range (0,lengthmodified): #Outter for loop runs an amount of times equal to the variable "length".
        prestringresult = 0
        templist = []
        for y in range (x,x + length): #Fills list with ids for new line
            templist.append(y)
        for d in range (0,lengthmodified): #Ignores an id from each line, increasing by one with each line, and starting with 0 for the first
            answerlist.append(templist[d])
        lengthmodified -= 1
        x += length    
        for n in answerlist: #XORs all of the numbers in the list via a loop and saves to prestringresult
            prestringresult ^= n
        stringresult = str(prestringresult) 
        answerlist = [] #Emptys list
        answerlist.append(int(stringresult)) #Adds the result of XORing all of the numbers in the list to the answer list
    #print(answerlist[0]) #Print statement allows value that's being returned to be checked, just uncomment it
    return (answerlist[0]) #Returns Answer



#start = timeit.default_timer()
answer(17,4)
#stop = timeit.default_timer()
#print (stop - start)
```

Comment: You have two inner loops. Try and get rid of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll likely need a different approach, not just minor improvements like John's. I just wrote a solution that can do `answer(0, 50000)` in about 2 seconds on my PC. I still do it row by row, but instead of xoring all numbers in the row's range, I do it bit by bit. How many numbers in the row have the 1-bit set?<sup>[*]</sup> An odd number of numbers? Then I flip the 1-bit of my answer. And then the same with for the 2-bit, the 4-bit, the 8-bit, etc, up to the 2<sup>30</sup>-bit. So for each row, it's just 31 little calculations (instead of actually xoring tens of thousands of numbers).

[*] Can be computed quickly in constant time just from start/stop of the range.

**Edit:** Since you asked for another hint, here's how to compute how often the 1-bit is set in some range(a, b). Compute how often it's set in the range(0, a) and subtract that from how often it's set in the range(0, b). It's easier if the range starts at zero. How often is the 1-bit set in some range(0, c)? Easy: `c//2` times. So how often is the 1-bit set in some range(a, b)? Simply `b//2 - a//2` times. The higher bits are similar, just a little more complicated.

**Edit 2:** Oh wait, I just remembered... there's an easy way to compute the xor of all numbers in some range(a, b). Again split the work into doing range(0, a) and range(0, b). The xor of all numbers in some range(0, c) is easy because there's a nice pattern (you'll see it if you do it for all c from 0 to let's say 30). Using this, I now solve `answer(0, 50000)` in about **0.04 seconds**.

Comment: You're correct. I trimmed the fat that John mentioned, and it cut down on the run-time tremendously, however it still wasn't good enough. Your solution sounds really intriguing and the 1.52 run-time sounds great. However, I'm not familiar with the process of xoring "bit by bit" as you mentioned. Is there maybe a website or stackoverflow post you can steer me to that explains that process?

Comment: @Mrcitrusboots Can't think of a good tutorial, sorry. But it's really just like I described, very simple. The result has (up to) 31 bits, and you can easily compute them independently. Try to solve an easier version of the problem first: Find out whether the result is even or odd. That is, find out its 0-bit. Then do the full problem by computing the other 30 bits as well.

Comment: Oooh, I'm pretty sure I understand now. One last question though. How are you able to compute "in constant time just from the start/stop of the rage"?

Comment: @Mrcitrusboots See the new edit of my answer. (And small correction: in my previous comment I of course meant 1-bit, not 0-bit.)

Comment: Why are there only 31 calculations? Isn't the integer 32-bit? Or is it just 31 calculations because the most significant bit is used for the sign of the integer?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Because the problem says *"All worker IDs (including the first worker) are between 0 and 2000000000 inclusive"*.

Comment: Oh okay. I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanPochmann is there any rule for non-consecutive ranges?

Comment: @tinySandy I'm not sure. If the step value is a power of 2, then of course there is, but for example for step=3, I don't see a pattern.

Comment: @StefanPochmann i was just doing the same task from google and it's pretty fast up to a point where i have to do XOR of chunks, that part can take forever, i did the bruteforce first and it turned out to be not fast at all, so i researched another algorithm for consecutive ranges, it works pretty fast but google complecated it so it's not a range from 0 to n, but it's range from 0 to n with gaps

Comment: @tinySandy Not sure what you're saying. Do you still have a problem or not?

Comment: @StefanPochmann yeah i still have a problem, in you example you use range from 0 to 50000, what if you have non-consecutive list, like [1, 4, 7, 8, 10 and so on]

Comment: @tinySandy No idea where your "[1, 4, 7, 8, 10 and so on]" is coming from and what your "and so on" means. In any case, I did **not** just do a single range, I solved the given problem.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Maybe i'm not getting the task rught but in task you have to return checksum which is XOR of non-consecutive sequence of integers it looks like diagonal half of the matrix

Comment: @StefanPochmann i see the part where you calculate xor for each row but i don't see the part where you calculate xor between the rows, can you point me? And both Edits are for consecutive sequences

Comment: @tinySandy Calculate xor between the rows? Yes, just do exactly that. That's the trivial part.

Comment: @StefanPochmann This is the place where i have a problem, because i have several millions of calculated rows and it takes forever to do xor between them, is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: @tinySandy Millions of rows? But you said you were "doing the same task from google". That's clearly not the case then.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, if you have answer(0, 5000000) you gonna have to work on 5000000 rows, each one of them gonna be trimmed at the end by the number of the row, am i wrong?

Comment: @tinySandy No, in that case there are only **401** rows (the last row just having worker ID 2000000000, the stated maximum).

Comment: @StefanPochmann i think i'm confused, when we do answer(0, 5000000) it's going to be a matrix 5000000 on 5000000, can you elaborate a little bit on how you determine rows, i think i'm fundamentally wrong

Comment: @tinySandy Seriously? What do *you* think row 401 looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138427/discussion-between-tinysandy-and-stefan-pochmann).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the people would get Time limit exceeded in this question. I did!
This question can be concluded in this way: "Find the XOR of all the numbers that lies between certain range in constant time." Yes, Constant time!

So from 3-6, the answer should be 3^4^5^6 = 4 in O(1) time.

Solution: 
XOR are associative in nature. So A ^ B ^ C can be written as B ^ A ^ C.
Also, we know that XOR means: 'AND'ing the same bits result into True i.e 1 and different bits result into 2.

From these 2 nature we can write:
XOR between all the numbers from 3-6 can be written as:

```
3^4^5^6 = (0^1^2)^(0^1^2) ^ (3^4^5^6)
        = (0^1^2^3^4^5^6) ^ (0^1^2) (this comes from the associative nature of xor)
        = XOR betn all the numbers from (0-6) ^ XOR betn all the numbers from (0-2)...eq(1)
```

So Now if we can find XOR of all the numbers from 0 to certain integer in a constant time, we will get our answer.

Luckily, there exists a pattern for us:

See this for an example:

```
(0-1): 0 ^ 1 = 1 (1)
(0-2): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 = 3 (2+1)
(0-3): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 = 0 (0)
(0-4): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 = 4 (4)

(0-5): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 = 1 (1)
(0-6): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 = 7 (6+1)
(0-7): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^  7 = 0 (0)
(0-8): 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 8 = 8 (8)


So the pattern for finding the xor between all the integers between 0 to n is:
if n%4 == 1 then, answer = 1
if n%4 == 2 then, answer = n+1
if n%4 == 3 then, answer = 0
if n%4 == 0 then answer = n 

Therefore, XOR(0-6) becomes 7 (since 6%4 ==2) and XOR(0-2) becomes 3 (since 2%4 ==2)

Therefore, the eq(1) now becomes:
3^4^5^6 = 7 ^ 3 = 4
```

Now the question is quite easy, most of us get stuck because of the time limit exceeded error, because we try to xor in each loop which would be huge if the number of input/iteration increases.
Here is my working solution in python for which all the test cases were passed by google:

```
#Main Program
def answer(start, length):
    checkSum = 0
    for l in range(length, 0, -1):
        checkSum = checkSum ^ (getXor(start + l-1) ^ getXor(start-1))
        start = start + length
    return checkSum

def getXor(x):
    result = [x, 1, x+1, 0]
    return result[x % 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a little improvement without using list, but it still will fail on large numbers. Nested loops kill speed. I think you need to follow Pochmann logic as brute force is rarely the way to go for these types of problems.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Neither `templist` nor `answerlist` are really needed. Let's take a couple passes at your code to see how to eliminate them.

1. First, let's make `templist`'s initialization a one-liner. This:

   ```
   templist = []
   for y in range (x,x + length):
       templist.append(y)
   ```

   Becomes this:

   ```
   templist = list(range(x, x + length))
   ```
2. Then let's do the same for `answerlist`. This:

   ```
   for d in range (0,lengthmodified):
       answerlist.append(templist[d])
   ```

   Becomes this:

   ```
   answerlist.extend(templist[:lengthmodified])
   ```
3. Now let's take a look at how they're used later. If we ignore `lengthmodified -= 1` and `x += length` for now, we have:

   ```
   templist = list(range(x, x + length))
   answerlist.extend(templist[:lengthmodified])

   for n in answerlist:
       prestringresult ^= n

   answerlist = []
   ```

   Instead of extending `answerlist`, iterating over it, and then clearing it, it'd be faster to just iterate over `templist`.

   ```
   templist = list(range(x, x + length))

   for n in templist[:lengthmodified]:
       prestringresult ^= n
   ```

   And now there's no need for `templist` either, so let's skip building it as well.

   ```
   for n in range(x, x + lengthmodified):
       prestringresult ^= n
   ```

   `templist` and `answerlist` are gone.

The only missing piece here is working `answerlist.append(int(stringresult))` back in. I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Overall, the lesson here is to avoid explicit `for` loops whenever you can. Writing lots of `for` loops that iterate over containers is a C way of thinking. In Python there are often ways to chew through collections all at once. Doing so lets you leverage the language's speedy builtin operations.

As a bonus, idiomatic Python is plain easier to read, too.

Comment: How much faster does this make it?